# How to use dplyr to fill cells meeting a criteria with the value of the cell immediately above iteratively?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use base R or dplyr to fill dataframe column cells that meet a specified criteria (value of 0 in this case) with the last value above before the 0. So, suppose we have the below data frame `myDF`, with columns `Element`, `Group`, `eleCnt`, and `reSeq` generated by the code immediately beneath. I would like to either add a new column "**ADD**" or modify the existing column `reSeq` with the manually input values I show under "ADD". Any recommendations for doing this in Base R or dplyr?

```
   Element Group eleCnt reSeq
   <chr>   <dbl>  <int> <dbl>  ADD  << ADD Explained
 1 R           0      1     1    1     since reSeq not 0 use current row reSeq value
 2 R           0      2     2    2     same as above
 3 X           0      1     1    1     same as above
 4 X           1      2     2    2     same as above
 5 X           1      3     0    2     since reSeq = 0 use reSeq value from last row prior to the 0
 6 X           0      4     4    4     since reSeq not 0 use current row reSeq value
 7 X           0      5     5    5     same as above
 8 X           0      6     6    6     same as above
 9 B           0      1     1    1     same as above
10 R           0      3     3    3     same as above
11 R           2      4     4    4     same as above
12 R           2      5     0    4     since reSeq = 0 use reSeq value from last row prior to the 0
13 X           3      7     7    7     since reSeq not 0 use current row reSeq value
14 X           3      8     0    7     since reSeq = 0 use last reSeq value <> 0 above
15 X           3      9     0    7     since reSeq = 0 use last reSeq value <> 0 above

myDF %>% 
  group_by(Element) %>%
    mutate(eleCnt = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup()%>%
  mutate(reSeq = ifelse(Group == 0 | Group != lag(Group), eleCnt,0) 
  )
```

Running dput(myDF):

```
> dput(myDF)
structure(list(Element = c("R", "R", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "B", "R", "R", "R", "X", "X", "X"), Group = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may change the 0s to `NA` and then do a group by `fill`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>%
   mutate(ADD = na_if(reSeq, 0)) %>%
   group_by(Element) %>%
   fill(ADD) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 5
   Element Group eleCnt reSeq   ADD
   <chr>   <dbl>  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 R           0      1     1     1
 2 R           0      2     2     2
 3 X           0      1     1     1
 4 X           1      2     2     2
 5 X           1      3     0     2
 6 X           0      4     4     4
 7 X           0      5     5     5
 8 X           0      6     6     6
 9 B           0      1     1     1
10 R           0      3     3     3
11 R           2      4     4     4
12 R           2      5     0     4
13 X           3      7     7     7
14 X           3      8     0     7
15 X           3      9     0     7
```

---

The steps in the creation of 'ADD' can be simplified from the original data 'myDF'

```
library(data.table)
myDF %>% 
  mutate(ADD =  rowid(Element) * NA^!(Group == 0 |!duplicated(Group))) %>% 
 group_by(Element) %>% 
 fill(ADD) %>% 
 ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   Element Group   ADD
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 R           0     1
 2 R           0     2
 3 X           0     1
 4 X           1     2
 5 X           1     2
 6 X           0     4
 7 X           0     5
 8 X           0     6
 9 B           0     1
10 R           0     3
11 R           2     4
12 R           2     4
13 X           3     7
14 X           3     7
15 X           3     7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Element = c("R", "R", "X", "X", "X", "X", "X", 
"X", "B", "R", "R", "R", "X", "X", "X"), Group = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3), eleCnt = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L), reSeq = c(1, 2, 
1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3, 4, 0, 7, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -15L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I saw your comment about using dput(). I assumed it was a typo for "output". So I ran ?dput and I see it shows DF structure. I edited the post with this, I'm not sure this is what you meant. You're not the 1st person to ask for this!

Comment: @Village.Idyot I did request for the dput.  the `df1` I used is from the output you got from your code (with `reSeq`).  I assume you want to add the `ADD` column in that output